# List Item Selected Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a following code:

```
foreach (ListItem item in lstCreate.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
        strCreateNewVideoCategory += item.Value + ":0,";
    else
        strCreateNewVideoCategory += item.Value + ":1,";
}
```

Am using this procedure,item.Selected is false every time,even when am selecting an item from the list of items.what am i doing wrong?

Note: ListItem using a user control (ascx).

Comment: Concatenating strings in a loop is a bad practice. If your list is relatively short it might not be a serious issue here, but regardless I think it would be a good idea that you  get into the habit of using a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You must try with this code for binding

   ```
   if (!IsPostback)
   { 
       BindYourControl();
   }
   ```

   Because you load and bind your control every time that you post, so you erase the selected value
2. Use the ViewState in order to persist.

   ```
   EnableViewState = true;
   ```

Comment: Sorry I initialized the controls every time page loads.Now i Corrected with step:1 its working fine now.Thankz

Comment: I'am happy to help you karthik

Comment: I don't get this, where and when you use `BindYourControl();`? is this a built in function?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me.  You should try putting a breakpoint to really see where you gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

check your autopostback event for pageload and for selected item use

```
 listitem_selectedindexchanged()
{
}
```

it will give you selected item's value

Answer (score 0):

Anyway,

```
foreach (ListItem item in lstCreate.Items)
{
    str += item.Value + item.Selected ? ":0," : ":1,";
}
```

or better

```
str = String.Join(
    ",",
    lstCreate.Items.Cast<ListItem>.Select(item => item.Value + item.Selected ? ":0" : ":1");
```